# Install nemiver in CentOS 7

Tags: centos

I am trying to install `nemiver` debugger in my CentOS machine. I followed the instructions listed here: [Walkthrough](http://jonathonreinhart.blogspot.com/2014/12/installing-nemiver-on-centos-7.html).

I got stuck however because despite the successful installation of `gtksourceviewmm-3.0`, I cannot complete the configuration of `nemiver` successfully.

I get this error again:

```
$./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
configure error: No package 'gtksourceviewmm-3.0' found
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The `./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64` command mentioned in your linked blog post is related to building `gtksourceviewmm-3.0`, not `nemiver`. Most likely `gtksourceviewmm-3.0` was installed to `/usr/local` and is therefore not available to `pkgconfig` (which takes care of checking library presence).

Comment: So how does one make the `gtksourceviewmm` installation available to `pkgconfig` then?